# Include value from cte when it has not match

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, postgresql-8.4

In my table I have some entries which - by the table's date column - is not older than 2016-01-04 (January 4, 2016).
Now I would like to make a query which more or less counts the number of rows which have a specific date value, but I'd like this query to be able to return a 0 count for dates not present in table.

I have this:

```
with date_count as (select '2016-01-01'::date + CAST(offs || ' days' as
interval) as date from generate_series(0, 6, 1) AS offs ) select
date_count.date, count(allocation_id) as packs_used from medicine_allocation,
date_count where site_id = 1 and allocation_id is not null and timestamp
between date_count.date and date_count.date + interval '1 days' group by
date_count.date order by date_count.date;
```

This surely gives me a nice aggregated view of the date in my table, but since no rows are from before January 4 2016, they don't show in the result:

```
"2016-01-04 00:00:00";1
"2016-01-05 00:00:00";2
"2016-01-06 00:00:00";4
"2016-01-07 00:00:00";3
```

I would like this:

```
"2016-01-01 00:00:00";0
"2016-01-02 00:00:00";0
"2016-01-03 00:00:00";0
"2016-01-04 00:00:00";1
"2016-01-05 00:00:00";2
"2016-01-06 00:00:00";4
"2016-01-07 00:00:00";3
```

I have also tried right join on the cte, but this yields the same result. I cannot quite grasp how to do this... any help out there?

Best,
Janus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need a `left join`:

```
with date_count as (
      select '2016-01-01'::date + CAST(offs || ' days' as
interval) as date
      from generate_series(0, 6, 1) AS offs
     )
select dc.date, count(ma.allocation_id) as packs_used
from date_count dc left join
     medicine_allocation ma
     on ma.site_id = 1 and ma.allocation_id is not null and
        ma.timestamp between dc.date and dc.date + interval '1 days'
group by dc.date
order by dc.date;
```

A word of advice:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

You will also notice that the `where` conditions were moved to the `ON` clause.  That is necessary because they are on the second table.

Comment: excellent!! Thank you so much. I was quite close myself (with my right join), but your help has saved me from much frustration :) Can I please ask why not to use comma, but join syntax only?

Comment: @JanusEngstrøm . . . `JOIN` syntax is more powerful.  There is no reason to use a comma (you can use `CROSS JOIN` instead).  Most people find the logic easier to follow with `JOIN`.